# How to read image from numpy array into PIL Image?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, lmdb

I am trying to read an image from a numpy array using PIL, by doing the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
#img is a np array with shape (3,256,256)
Image.fromarray(img)
```

and am getting the following error:

```
File "...Image.py", line 2155, in fromarray
    raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")
```

I think this is because `fromarray` expects the shape to be `(height, width, num_channels)` however the array I have is in the shape `(num_channels, height, width)` as it is stored in this was in an `lmdb` database.

How can I reshape the Image so that it is compatible with `Image.fromarray`?

Comment: maybe try `Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img))`

Comment: The type of array is uint8, the problem is in the shape

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to reshape. [This is what rollaxis is for](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html):

```
Image.fromarray(np.rollaxis(img, 0,3))
```

Comment: This. A [C, H, W] array will be rolled to [H, W, C]. Note that it will work only when len(shape) == 3

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
img = np.reshape(256, 256, 3)
Image.fromarray(img)
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining the datatype of the numpy array to `np.uint8` fixed it for me.

```
>>> img = np.full((256, 256), 3)
>>> Image.fromarray(img)
...
line 2753, in fromarray
raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type: %s, %s" % typekey) from e
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1), <i8
```

So defining the array with the proper datatype:

```
>>> img = np.full((256, 256), 3, dtype=np.uint8)
>>> Image.fromarray(img)
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=256x256 at 0x7F346EA31130>
```

creates the Image object successfully

Or you could simply modify the existing numpy array:

```
img = img.astype(np.uint8)
```